# Setting Firebase server time in Android App

Tags: android, firebase

I have this code in my Android application, creating a new record in Firebase.

```
Firebase searchRef = myFirebaseRef.child("searches");
Firebase newPostRef = searchRef.push();
Map<String, String> search = new HashMap<String, String>();
search.put("start", start_address);
newPostRef.setValue(search);
String postId = newPostRef.getKey();
```

How would I go about inserting the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP into this record?

Comment: Since you've specified that `search` can only contain strings, you won't be able to insert the timestamp here ( it is an Object ). Change your HashMap to `<String, Object>` and then simply insert ServerValue.TIMESTAMP using the same `put()` as you use to set `start`

Comment: @Kato Thanks! that worked great... new to Firebase and even Android programming so I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to set the timestamp to a particular node

```
setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```